# Regarding Weyl's integration formula - from "equality up to scalar" to "exact equality"

Tags: rt.representation-theory, root-systems, weyl-group

Teaching a course on representations of compact groups, I want to prove Weyl's integration formula. It seems to me that in a few sources, they prove the formula up to scalar, and don't even acknowledge that (for example, in Adams's and Barry's books; Of course it might be that I don't understand something). In Brocker and Dieck's book, they do elaborate on that point in some geometric way (using $G \to G/T$ being a fibration).

Anyway, supposing that I know the formula up to scalar, in order to know the formula precisely I would like to know that $\prod_{\alpha \in R} (e^{\alpha} - 1) = |W| + ...$. Here, $R$ is the set of roots, $e^{\alpha}$ can be thought of formally, and $|W|+...$ means an element $|W|\cdot e^0$ plus a linear combination of $e^{\lambda}$'s for non-zero $\lambda$.

Can one show that this equation holds by playing with the root system (or maybe in some other nice way)?

Thank you

Comment: In Brocker and tom Dieck's book, Lemma 1.9(i) in Ch. IV explains where the factor of $|W|$ ultimately comes from, so are you asking for an alternative (more direct) way to handle their verification that $c=1$ in the proof of 1.7 in Ch. IV?  If so, Theorem 2.1 in  http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210CPage/handouts/det(dq).pdf  (a course based on the same book) seems like it may address what you seek (to get the  integration formula on the nose on the first pass, not only up to scalar and then needing to go back and nail it down at the end).

Comment: @nfdc23 Thank you. Yes, I meant that they show $c = 1$ in some way. But I wondered if I can first ignore this, so to get the formula up to scalar, and then "nail the scalar" without differential geometry or topology, just by plugging in the function $f = 1$ and seeing what the scalar should be (and then I obtain the root-theoretic question written above). Anyway, thank you, I will look at your reference.

Comment: You're welcome. One more thought: in a course on compact Lie groups, the audience might not be familiar with root systems at that stage (it is motivated by topics that come much later in the theory, as you know). So from the viewpoint of a (typical) student, it might not be so illuminating to see root systems used to take care of this issue.

Comment: @nfdc23 Thank you for your thoughts, they are very much appreciated. I first showed that every element can be conjugated to a maximal torus as in Brocker and Dieck, thus almost doing Weyl's integration formula. Then I passed to root systems, because I approach G-modules via weight theory, so roots come naturally, as moving us between different weights. I thus postponed Weyl's integration formula to the end, before showing Weyl's character formula more or less. In other words, we did already talked about roots, so in my head it seemed natural to use this to "nail down" the scalar.

Comment: @ndfc23 By the way, I looked at your reference now. It is nice and detailed, but unfortunately only performs (if I understand correctly) what I did already - computation of the jacobian. What is missing (if I understand correctly) is that if the top form on $G$ is taken so that total mass is $1$, and the same on $T$, it is not clear what the total mass of $G/T$ will be with the induced form - hence the scalar. Anyway, it is OK, I will choose some way of showing what I want.

Comment: For locally compact Hausdorff $G$ and $H$, for left Haar measures on $G$ and $H$ there is a necessary and sufficient condition involving a "modulus character" - always met in the compact case - for existence of a unique left $G$-invariant measure with the usual regularity properties on $G/H$ so that "coset Fubini" holds on $C_c$-spaces (and then the $L^1$-version holds); see Lang's book *Real and Functional Analysis*. In the Lie-group setting, use test functions to show that measure arises from the expected top-degree left-invariant differential form on $G/H$. Maybe this is your strategy too.